Why does omitting a property on a union type breaks the type?
I have the following types in my project:
export interface BaseTravelpayoutsPricesV3Options {
    currency    ?: string;
    departure_at?: string;
    return_at   ?: string;
    direct      ?: boolean;
    limit       ?: number;
    page        ?: number;
    sorting     ?: 'price' | 'route';
    unique      ?: boolean;
    one_way     ?: boolean;
}

export interface TravelpayoutsPricesV3OptionsWithOrigin {
    origin: string;
}

export interface TravelpayoutsPricesV3OptionsWithDestination {
    destination: string;
}

export interface TravelpayoutsPricesV3OptionsWithOriginAndDestination {
    origin     : string;
    destination: string;
}

export type TravelpayoutsPricesV3Options =
    BaseTravelpayoutsPricesV3Options
    & 
    (
        TravelpayoutsPricesV3OptionsWithOrigin
        | 
        TravelpayoutsPricesV3OptionsWithDestination
        | 
        TravelpayoutsPricesV3OptionsWithOriginAndDestination
    );

Now when I'm trying to omit some property from that type for function argument, tha call says I'm specifiyng unknown property even though it's not the one I omitted.
function test(options: Omit<TravelpayoutsPricesV3Options, 'limit'>) {
    return 'foo';
}

test({
    origin: 'test', // Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'origin' does not exist in type 'Omit<TravelpayoutsPricesV3Options, "limit">'
})

Why does that happen?

You options can be BaseTravelpayoutsPricesV3Options & TravelpayoutsPricesV3OptionsWithDestination ,  but origin does not exist in TravelpayoutsPricesV3OptionsWithDestination. So it throws the error. What is your test function expect?

Omit<T, K> isn't distributive over unions in T. You can write your own DistributiveOmit if you need that functionality. See the linked q/a above and this playground link.
